# How can I get the parent object id inside the child model? Nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, nested-forms

I hava a **Campaign** and a **Material** models.

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :materials

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :materials, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

end
```

and

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :campaign

  def code=(val)
    new_code = val
    suffixes = %w(.png .jpg .jpeg .gif .bmp)
    urls = URI.extract(new_code, ['http', 'https'])
    urls.each do |url|

      new_code = new_code.gsub(url, "#{url}&var1=#{self.campaign.id}") unless url.ends_with? *suffixes #<--- (this is not working
    end
    write_attribute(:code, new_code)
  end
end
```

**Material** has an attribute **code**, and I want to fill this attribute code with a link that contains the id of the related **Campaign**, while creating it.

How can I get the object **Campaign** inside the **Material** model?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I didn't explain very well. In the above **Material** model I want to get the parent id to populate the code attribute, during the *"create campaign process"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a `before_save` callback and `self.campaign.id` to get the parent id inside a method to manipulate the info my user typed.

Answer (score 1):

It's `belongs_to :campaign` not `:campaigns`   ... use the singular since each material is for one campaign.

Defining `belongs_to` and `has_many` automatically gives you methods for retrieving the objects.

```
my_material = Material.first
my_material.campaign # <- this gives you the campaign object
my_material.campaign_id # <- this gives you the campaign object's id
my_material.campaign.id 
# ^ another way, slightly less efficient but more robust as you no longer need to know how the records are coupled
```

If you're in the `create campaign` process and you haven't persisted the campaign, then you don't have an id to work with, but you can fix that with an `after_save` call back in the campaign that can update materials' `code` attribute with the necessary id.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain my problem very well, I've just updated my question.